# If a Parent has multiple children what determines which status it will retrieve on WEXITSTATUS?

Tags: c

I'm sorry I'm not fluent with the mechanics of fork(), so the answer may very well be simple. To elaborate on my question, if I run fork() multiple times, say with a for loop, and I use WEXITSTATUS(status) to retrieve information from the/a child, what determines whose information I gain?

Answer (score 2):

The [`wait()` or `waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) function returns the PID of the corpse, and the status value is the status belonging to that corpse.

```
int   status;
pid_t corpse = wait(&status);

if (corpse > 0)
{
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
        printf("Process %d died with exit status %d\n", (int)pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        printf("Process %d died from signal %d\n", (int)pid, WTERMSIG(status));
    else
        printf("Process %d was reported with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)pid, status);
}
```

You can find out about core dumps on most actual systems (usually `WCOREDUMP(signal)`), but POSIX doesn't standardize that.  The options covered by the `else` clause include `WIFSTOPPED` and `WIFCONTINUED`, and maybe some others.  Consult the `waitpid()` man page for your system.